# Hyper link is applied to only half of the word

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I am trying to apply hyperlink to this text, The problem i am facing is the link is only applied to the "Business" and not to the analyst. I am working on a Microsoft Sharepoint Enviorment

```css
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 430px;
  left: 28%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <a href="Link">Business Analyst</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should post the whole html/css code, because I just tested the code above and the link is applied correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :
close the a tag between the two words .

I'm sorry because there is no code . I'm still new .

Comment: Why didn't you add some code? what do you mean by "im still new"

Comment: I still new in stack overflow . I was not know how to insert the code . I was try but i fail

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, So my hyperlink was bleeding into another container the moment i moved my text away from the container it worked